# Windows 8 on iSCSI with LIO target: thin provisioning

Tags: linux, iscsi, windows-8.1

I have installed Windows 8.1 on an iSCSI target. This target is provided by Linux LIO and is backed by a sparse file.

One of the reasons I created such an installation was thin provisioning. In other words, when I free disk space on Windows, LIO should punch holes into the file, thus free storage space on the Linux server as well.

I have checked my kernel's sources and the SCSI UNMAP command is really supported for file-backed targets. On the other hand, deleting files on Windows doesn't lower the amount of space taken by the backing file on Linux (checked with `du`). Actually, the backing file sometimes grows even more.

Some sources on Google say Win8 should support UNMAP/DISCARD on iSCSI, but even in Wireshark I only see ordinary read and write commands when files are being deleted. Any way to fix or troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the `emulate_tpu` attribute is enabled for backstore (sparse file you have created and attached as LUN to iscsi target)

Comment: You're right, it is disabled. I'll try if it helps. BTW who gave the downvote?!

Comment: Don't know..glad it helped

Comment: It helped in the sense that Windows now sends UNMAP commands, the amount of used space (reported by `du`) is however still not decreasing :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the target published that it supports UNMAP, you can read how Windows expects the target to show it in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj123660.aspx The important part is in the INQUIRY page B0h.